# How to start and use java webservices

Tags: java, web-services

I would like to experiment with some code which uses the "com.sun.xml.wss.XWSSProcessor".
I am no java expert and would like to know where I can find the correct jar files.

Do I need to install extra packages except JavaSE (7)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Here is step by step tutorial to creating WebServices in Netbeans https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/jax-ws.html

Answer (score 0):

It is comes with JAVA 6. That class can be found at com.sun.xml.wss/xws-security/3.0/com/sun/xml/wss/XWSSProcessor.java in source repo.

Pleas refer the following XML and Web Services Security Project.It contains the details of that security implementations.

https://xwss.java.net/